# Linq Left Outer Join - DefaultIfEmpty Error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

There is a collection of devices types, some of which support configuration setting(s).
I'm trying to get a list of all device types, and any applicable settings.

This query isn't picking up devices that have no DeviceParameters. If I add the .DefaultIfEmpty() as shown below, I get this error:

*"The cast to value type 'Int64' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."*

What's the correct synatx for DefaultIfEmpty?

```
            var Devices = from d in dc.DeviceTypes
                      join p in dc.DeviceParameters on d.TypeID equals p.TypeID into tmpTable
                      from items in tmpTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      group items by d.DeviceName into g
                      select new
                      {
                          DeviceName = g.Key,
                          settings = from s in g
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         ParamName = s.ParamName,
                                         Param1 = s.Param1,
                                         Param2 = s.Param2,
                                         Param3 = s.Param3
                                     }
                      };
```

Comment: Have you tried casting both TypeIDs to nullable int? "on (int?)d.TypeID equals (int?)p.TypeID into"...

Comment: Jacob: Thanks for the suggestion, but the same error occurs even with the cast.

Comment: :). Worth a shot and thanks for the update. Glad you got a qualified answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have defined the foreign key relationship, I think the solution is pretty straightforward, unless I'm missing something:

```
var Devices = dc.DeviceTypes
    .Select(p=>new 
        {
             DeviceName = p.DeviceName ,
             settings = p.DeviceParameters
                 .Select(q=>new
                 {
                     ParamName = p.ParamName,
                     Param1 = q.Param1,
                     Param2 = q.Param2,
                     Param3 = q.Param3
                 })
        });
```

Anyways, I would probably do the settings part this way:

```
settings = p.DeviceParameters.ToList()
```

Comment: Fyi, p.DeviceParameters.ToList()  gave this error:   LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Instruments.DeviceParameters] ToList[DeviceParameters](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Instruments.DeviceParameters])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Ohhh I see. Didn't know it doesn't work that way, I'm kind of new to LINQ to entities. Thx for sharing =)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue that you are seeing with your query is that by using the `DefaultIfEmpty()` call you are then trying to pull values out of a null object.  If you have a valid DeviceType but don't have any DeviceParameters mapped then when it is trying to materialize the settings property with this statement:

```
settings = from s in g
select new
{
    ParamName = s.ParamName,
    Param1 = s.Param1,
    Param2 = s.Param2,
    Param3 = s.Param3
}
```

It is trying to create a new object and the object for "s" is null so trying to access the property ParamName or Param1, etc. won't work.  I tried the same code within LINQPad and when I removed the DefaultIfEmpty() call then everything worked.

Without knowing the properties and their types I can't be certain but like I said, based on implementing similar code in LINQPad I got similar results.